# c++ program debugged well with Cygwin4 (under Netbeans 7.2) but not with MinGW (under QtCreator 4.8.1)

Tags: c++, qt4, cygwin, mingw, netbeans-7

I have a c++ program that takes a map text file and outputs it to a graph data structure I have made. I am using QT as I needed cross-platform program and GUI as well as visual representation of the map. I have several maps in different sizes (8x8 to 4096x4096).
I am using unordered_map with a vector as key and vertex as value, I'm sending hash(1) and equal functions which I wrote to the unordered_map in creation.

Under QT I am debugging my program with QT 4.8.1 for desktop MinGW (QT SDK), the program works and debugs well until I try the largest map of 4096x4096, then the program gets stuck with the following error:

> the inferior stopped because it received a signal from operating system

When debugging, the program halts at the hash function which used inside the unordered_map and not as part of the insertion state, but at a getter(2).

Under Netbeans IDE 7.2 and Cygwin4 all works fine (debug and run).

Some code info:

```
    typedef std::vector<double> coordinate;
`typedef std::unordered_map<coordinate const*, Vertex<Element>*, container_hash, container_equal> vertexsContainer;`

`vertexsContainer *m_vertexes`
```

(1) hash function:

```
struct container_hash
{
    size_t operator()(coordinate const *cord) const
    {
        size_t sum = 0;
        std::ostringstream ss;

        for ( auto it = cord->begin() ; it != cord->end() ; ++it )
        {
           ss << *it;
        }

        sum = std::hash<std::string>()(ss.str());
        return sum;
    }
};
```

(2) the getter:

```
template <class Element>
Vertex<Element> *Graph<Element>::getVertex(const coordinate &cord)
{
    try
    {
        Vertex<Element> *v = m_vertexes->at(&cord);
        return v;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe it was some memory issue at the beginning, so before I was thinking of trying Netbeans I checked it with QT on my friend pc with a 16GB RAM and got the same error.

**Update:**
I try to run this on visual studio 2012, I got a bad_alloc error which halt my program, when looking at task manager I saw the memory assigned to the program was going up to 2GB, could be it's because it's a 32bit program?

**Update**
I debugged my program under Netbeans with 32bit architecture and Cygwin4 and all worked fine, so maybe it is not a 32 bit problem, also the memory used with netbeans was 1.5GB, so how in MinGW and VS2012 it's going up to 2GB?

Comment: You mean QtCreator, I suppose. And yes, on 32 bit versions of Windows a program has a 2 GB virtual address space (3 GB if the system is set in a particular way and the executable is linked with a particular flag). This means that you cannot allocate more than 2 GB of memory (unless you use platform-specific tricks like mapping only some portions of your allocated memory at once).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I debugged my program under Netbeans with 32bit architecture and Cygwin4 and all worked fine, so how can you explain that?

Comment: Are you using the same settings? In particular, I suspect that under VS and QtCreator you are using the debug settings, which may use more memory for each allocation/element for debug/security features.

Comment: I'm using the debug settings in Netbeans, VS and QtCreator...

Comment: Probably in one case the debug features take more memory for each allocation/element. To make a meaningful comparison you should compile in release mode.